# Inheritance of protocol methods

Tags: objective-c

I have a base class which implements NSDecimalNumberBehavior protocol methods. Now when i inherit this class would the child class inherit the implemented protocol methods? I assumed it does and i set the child class as the delegate. But my code crashes.

Comment: "Crashes" is a bit vague. What is the exact error you get and where does it happen? You'll have to show the code where it happens, and the code around it. Please also explain the types used.

Comment: have you checked this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435604/protocol-inheritance-in-objective-c

Comment: Posting the crash log could help determine why it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

A subclass inherits it's superclass' instance variables, methods, and protocol conformance. Nothing strange or unexpected there.

And what is this `NSDecimalNumberBehavior` protocol you speak of? There is no such protocol in Foundation, and you **really should not** use the `NS` prefix for your own classes and protocols. `NS` is reserved by Apple to ensure their names never clashes with our names, make up your own prefix.