# How to force a class to declare a protocol - in a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, interface

Can you please hint at how to achieve the above mentioned?

I want to create a protocol A (an interface declaration) that will force all concrete implementations (classes) of that protocol A to declare a protocol B with which these classes will notify their delegates about something.

I guess my problem is conceptual and syntactical at the same time.

Comment: Sorry guys, the proper word should have been "...to declare"...not "..to implement"...I completely screwed up the meaning by this mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare your protocol as an extension of the protocol you want to enforce :

```
@protocol NewProtocol <OldProtocol>
    - (void)foo;
@end
```

That way you are sure that all the required methods of `OldProtocol` are implemented by any object implementing `NewProtocol`. Optional methods wont be enforced though, of course.

Comment: I want to achieve two different things
1) Declare an abstract interface (Protocol A), 
2) Force every concrete implementation of protocol A to declare 
  a) protocol B with two delegate callback methods 
  b) some standard instance methods

I am not sure if protocol inheritance solves this.

Comment: The protocol in itself and inheritance seems the only way to do that to me. If it does not look right in your situation then post your software structure to help us see the issue, and we could think of another architecture because it might be at fault here

Answer (score 1):

If you define Protocol A to inherit from Protocol B, then you will get the effect you are after.

You can even define both protocols in the same file.

There is more discussion about inheritance of protocols in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435604/protocol-inheritance-in-objective-c).